# Можно ли сохранить файлы программы (Unity,Visual studio,android stuido) переустановить windows, и использовать их снова. Возможно ли это?

Tags: windows, unity3d, android-studio, visual-studio

Вопрос такой хочу переустановить windows, описанные программы есть на ноуте. Можно ли папки программ просто скопировать,сохранить . И пользоваться после переустановки windows ? Как с играми например.

Comment: Вас беспокоят какие-то фалы настроек, или файлы с которыми Вы работаете? Или просто лень переустанавливать?

Comment: Не  хочу заново скачивать, устанавливать , так как интернет не очень. Файлы настроек всегда по дефолту, это не важно. Мне надо чтобы просто основные папки этих программ сохранить перед переустановкой , а потом их просто взять и использовать без переустановок . Ну чтобы программа работала (сама программа).

Comment: Нет, так работать не будет. Как минимум ещё надо все ветки реестра сохранить, которые относятся к программе. В результате гораздо проще будет переустановить и всё.

Comment: Но возможно ли с помощью программ, каких то , сделать бэкап реестера , а потом восстановить ? Может есть все таки выход.

Comment: Есть выход. Он называется `DevOps`. То про что ты спрашиваешь - решает именно эта область, но не так как ты это описываешь. Ну и сил на это надо потратить просто гору. Так что в конкретном местечковом случае поддержу @nightflash.

Comment: Тему можно закрывать. Спасибо всем кто отписался.